# Calculate the total of one of the columns listed in existing query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using wordpress and wpDataTables to display data in a table on a particular site. I have written an SQL query as follows;

```
SELECT items.form_id as 'Form ID',
MAX(IF(`field_id` = 88,meta_value,NULL)) AS 'User ID',
MAX(IF(`field_id` = 96,meta_value,NULL)) AS 'Display Name',
MAX(IF(`field_id` = 95,meta_value,NULL)) AS 'User Role',
MAX(IF(`field_id` = 301,meta_value,NULL)) AS 'Your District',
MAX(IF(`field_id` = 97,meta_value,NULL)) AS 'Time Duty Logged',
MAX(IF(`field_id` = 84,meta_value,NULL)) AS 'Date of Duty',
MAX(IF(`field_id` = 85,meta_value,NULL)) AS 'Duty Start Time',
MAX(IF(`field_id` = 86,meta_value,NULL)) AS 'Duty End Time',
MAX(IF(`field_id` = 139,meta_value,NULL)) AS 'Duty Status',
MAX(IF(`field_id` = 142,meta_value,NULL)) AS 'Duty Type',
MAX(IF(`field_id` = 174,meta_value,NULL)) AS 'Which Event?',
MAX(IF(`field_id` = 103,meta_value,NULL)) AS 'Total Hours',
MAX(IF(`field_id` = 135,meta_value,NULL)) AS 'Duty Details',
MAX(IF(`field_id` = 136,meta_value,NULL)) AS 'End Section',
MAX(IF(`field_id` = 227,meta_value,NULL)) AS 'User Details',
MAX(IF(`field_id` = 228,meta_value,NULL)) AS 'End Section'
FROM wp_frm_item_metas as meta
JOIN wp_frm_items as items  ON (items.id = meta.item_id)
WHERE items.form_id = 6
GROUP BY meta.item_id
```

Within wpDataTables it has the ability to add column filters which is great. What I want to do is calculate the total of

```
MAX(IF(`field_id` = 103,meta_value,NULL)) AS 'Total Hours',
```

to provide one single value calculated in the following format

```
TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(wp_frm_item_metas.meta_value))),'%H:%i' ) AS calculated_total
```

With the filters then used on the table this would update the total hours that appear on the page.

How would be best to tackle this to get a total of the hours that are shown in that column?

Once I get a numerical value I can then create a graph, chart that will display that total to screen.

Im not sure if it is even possible to query a query to give me what I want at the end of that one SQL statement.

Any thoughts and help would be greatly appreciated.

Wayne

Comment: What is the type of `field_id = 103`. Is it integer?

Comment: Sadly its a string, making it an integer rounds the figure up to the nearest whole number but I can make it either. I need it to retain minutes into the calculation.